# Transition with this.src=image1.src; on a onmouseover in html

Tags: html, css

```
<img src="images/home.png" onmouseover="this.src=image1.src;" onmouseout="this.src=image0.src;" id="imgHome">
```

Am I able to apply CSS transition to these 2 images, so it won't look to instant.

I'm considering doing it without this line and just make 2 seperate images, but I prefer it this way.

Comment: What did you just ask ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Right now i have 2 images that are switched when I mouse over and mouse out on it. It is all happening instantly, without any transition, but since it has 1 id, i can't really set a transition on it

Comment: Provide jsfiddle please

Comment: I have answered. Please look into it :)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do it with one `img` tag. Using background css property you can achieve it.

HTML:

```
<img id="image1">
```

CSS:

```
#image1
{
    background: url("http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg");
}

#image1:hover
{
    background: url("http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Rainbow%20Worm.jpg");
}

img
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

JSFiddle example: [Link to sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5YFeW/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Transitions are only for changing CSS properties. What you are doing is change path to image so no transitions can be made.

You can use jQuery for example to make transition (jQ has some simple animations or you can 
use some more advanced libraries).

If you want to use CSS then you can try to make 2 images one on to of another (using absolute positioning). Then on hover change opacity of bottom one from 1 to 0, and one at top from 0 to 1. If you apply transition to opacity it should make smooth transition.

```
<style>
    .img{position:relative;}
    .top{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    .bottom{opacity:1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     }
    .top:hover{opacity:1;}
    .bottom:hover{opacity:0;}
</style>
<div class="img">
    <img class="bottom" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=15">
    <img class="top" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=16">
</div>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/5kyBX/